# Java joining array of non-String into String with delimiters

Tags: java, string, join

I have got a POJO/Bean called `Person`. It has a customized `toString()` method.

I have also an array of `Person` called `presenters`:

```
Person[] presenters;
```

I want to join the presenters into one string with delimiter:

```
String presenters = String.join(", ", (CharSequence[]) presenters);
```

Note that to join into `String`, I need to cast `presetnters` into `CharSequence[]`, but I got this exception:

```
cannot be cast presenters to [Ljava.lang.CharSequence;
```

Is there any quick fix for this?

@Federico Thanks for the refer, but array isn't exactly a list.... though I guess I can convert the array to list first.

Comment: does `Person` override `toString()` method ?

Comment: Try `String presentersStr = Arrays.stream(presenters).map(Person::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));`

Comment: Well, if your Persons class does not implement the interface CharSequence, I dont see why you expect it to be able to be cast into that.

Comment: @jhamon Yes, `Person` overrides `toString()`

Comment: @Eritrean Thanks. I guess this is the simplest solution.